# magento REST/OAuth in 1.7

Tags: magento

I am in magento 1.6.2 and working on setting up something to show/hide cms page(s) based on customer status.

Similar to the way WordPress has many "paywall/membership" plugins.

So the user subscribes (currently looking at using AW SARP plug-in for that part) --> then magento grants access to the CMS page,

i.e.

- Show/Hide Plug-In
- Show/Hide Video Program links in Customer Account

A Video Program is a Product on a CMS Page.

```
Customer buys (or subscribes to) a Video Program 
-->a listener looks for customer ID 
-->customer ID is found and shows magento what product(s) (one or more products) customer has paid for (and/or is currently subscribed to) 
-->magento displays an array in customer account on a tab "My Purchased Videos" that includes links to CMS pages for each Video Program 
-->once subscription expires, customer can not access CMS pages for each Video Program.
```

So, am I right that 1.7 allows customer management /access to be done in a totally different way using REST/OAuth or is REST/OAuth is just one more admin thing?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the Magento REST API is primarily designed for integrating 3rd party applications, so it's "just" one more admin thing.